# I only did a brake fluid flush on one side before I had to stop and run an errand. Do I need to start over?

Tags: brakes, brake-fluid

I started flushing my brake fluid. I was able to do one side, but then I had to use the car to run an errand. Do I need to redo that side? Or is it okay to pick up where I left off?

Comment: Most brake systems are designed as dual diagonal; safety design for half the brake system still operating if a leak or damage occurs to any brake or lines. Brake master cylinders have two brake pistons in tandem. One piston for the right front/left rear, the second piston for the left front/right rear. If one side is damaged, the other half still works albeit with only half braking but better than none. Diagonal brakes are configured to allow even braking without pulling to one side.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to redo that side, as long as the fluid reservoir was filled with fresh fluid you are good to go, just do the other side as normal. There may be a very small amount of fluid from the old side mixing in with the new fluid, but that will be negligible and nothing to worry about.